# Suppressing Keyboard popup for a single Edittext

Tags: android

Long story short, I currently have a date picker dialog that pops up on click for an edittext attribute. Everything is working fine, except when the dialog pops up so does the soft keyboard.
I do not want to disable the keyboard for the other attributes on the page, and I do not want to leave it as is, because not only does it look sloppy and clunky, but it means the user can mess up my lovely formatted date object that goes nicely in to my database. Not good.

I've tried disabling the element in my XML file both as clickable and editable, to no avail. Code below, as usual.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextExpiryDate"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:hint="Card Expiry Date"
    android:editable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSecurityCode"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerCardType"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinnerCardType" />
```

And then the (somewhat messy) Java file, however the relevant parts are in bold.

```
public class RegisterFragmentPaymentInfo extends Fragment {

public Spinner creditCardSpinner;
public EditText cardNumberInput;
**public EditText expiryDateInput;**
public EditText securityCodeInput;
public Button proceedButton;

public String cardType;
public String cardNumber;
**public Date expiryDate;**
public int securityCode;

Bundle oldUserData;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


**DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateDateInput();
    }
};
private void updateDateInput(){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy");
    expiryDateInput.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
}**

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_payment_info, container, false);

    findInputFields(rootView);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> a = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(), R.array.credit_card_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    creditCardSpinner.setAdapter(a);
    creditCardSpinner.setPrompt("Please select your Card Type");

    proceedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            readUserInput();

            if (isValidInput()) {
                Bundle userData;
                userData = prepareDataToPass(oldUserData);

                RegisterFragmentConfirm targetFragment = new RegisterFragmentConfirm();
                targetFragment.setArguments(userData);
                FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                t.replace(R.id.fragment_login_main, targetFragment);
                t.addToBackStack(null);
                t.commit();

            }

        }
    });



    e**xpiryDateInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });**


    return rootView;
}

public void findInputFields(View tempView){
    creditCardSpinner = (Spinner) tempView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCardType);
    cardNumberInput = (EditText)tempView.findViewById(R.id.editTextCardNumber);
    expiryDateInput = (EditText)tempView.findViewById(R.id.editTextExpiryDate);
    securityCodeInput = (EditText) tempView.findViewById(R.id.editTextSecurityCode);
    proceedButton = (Button) tempView.findViewById(R.id.btnCompleteRegistrationStepThree);

    expiryDateInput.setFocusable(false);
}

public void readUserInput(){
    cardType = creditCardSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    cardNumber = cardNumberInput.getText().toString();

    try{
        if(securityCodeInput.getText().toString()!=null){
            if(securityCodeInput.getText().toString().length()==3||securityCodeInput.getText().toString().length()==4){
                securityCode = Integer.parseInt(securityCodeInput.getText().toString());
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Security Number invalid, please enter a valid Security Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Security Number is mandatory, please enter a Security Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Security Number must be numeric, please enter a valid Security Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy");
    try {
        expiryDate = s.parse(expiryDateInput.getText().toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public Boolean isValidInput(){
    Boolean inputIsValid = false;

    //Boolean validCardType; //Unnecessary; User cannot select other than supplied card types
    Boolean validCardNumber = false;
    Boolean validExpiryDate;
    //Boolean validSecurityCode; //Also unnecessary, validated upon initial input for simplicity.
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    String dateIntermediate;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (!cardNumber.isEmpty()){
        validCardNumber = true;
    }else if(cardNumber.isEmpty()){
        validCardNumber = false;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Card Number is mandatory, please enter a Card Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy");
    dateIntermediate = s.format(c.getTime());
    try {
        currentDate = s.parse(dateIntermediate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if(expiryDate.after(currentDate)){
        validExpiryDate =true;
    }
    else{
        validExpiryDate = false;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Card has expired, please use a Card that is within date, or check your given expiration is correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if(validExpiryDate&&validCardNumber){
        inputIsValid = true;
    }

    return inputIsValid;
}

public Bundle prepareDataToPass(Bundle previousUserData){
    Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
    newBundle.putAll(previousUserData);

    newBundle.putString("card_type", cardType);
    newBundle.putString("card_number", cardNumber);
    newBundle.putSerializable("expiry_date", expiryDate);
    newBundle.putInt("security_code", securityCode);

    return newBundle;
}
```

}

Comment: try focusable=false.

Comment: @DhavalPatel Worked like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is on your androidmanifest.xml at desired activity add this line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

so it looks like:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.yourdomain.user.AboutActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize" />
```

or you can add this line  to your onCreat to set keyboard hidden par default

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

> [`public void setFocusable (boolean focusable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusable%28boolean%29)
>
> Set
>   whether this view can receive the focus. Setting this to false will
>   also ensure that this view is not focusable in touch mode.

So, When you set focusable false for `EditText`. It can still detect click event but it will not open Keyboard as it's not able to acquire focus.

Answer (score 0):

create a dummy layout in your `xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```